# to_datetime Unrecognized value type: <class 'str'>

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am trying to convert the 'date' column from string to dateime data type

example of the 'date' column:

```
array(['2015-08-26 10:24:48.127', '2015-08-26 10:26:41.000',
       '2015-08-26 10:27:52.000', ..., '2015-08-26 10:18:11.000',
       '2015-08-26 10:21:39.000', '2015-08-26 10:23:05.000'], dtype=object)
```

Attempt at converting to datetime data type:
To get the date component from the date column
The date column in YYYY-MM-DD format.

````
order_items['date']= pd.to_datetime('date', format="%Y-%m-%d")```



However i got the following error:

```TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/datetimes.py in objects_to_datetime64ns(data, dayfirst, yearfirst, utc, errors, require_iso8601, allow_object)
   1857         try:
-> 1858             values, tz_parsed = conversion.datetime_to_datetime64(data)
   1859             # If tzaware, these values represent unix timestamps, so we

pandas/_libs/tslibs/conversion.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion.datetime_to_datetime64()

TypeError: Unrecognized value type: <class 'str'>```
````

Comment: just use `order_items['date'] = pd.to_datetime(order_items['date'])` - no need to provide the format explicitly here.

Answer (score 0):

you are passing `date` literal to the `pd.to_datetime` function, not the actual date.

if you do something like -

```py
pd.to_datetime('2015-08-26 10:24:48.127', format="%Y-%m-%d")
```

It should work.

Or if it is a column in dataframe(assuming named df)

```py
pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format="%Y-%m-%d")
```

Comment: Hi Yatharth, thanks for your feedback. I actually want to convert a pandas series from string to datetime format. Any solution if we want to convert for a pandas series?

Comment: Hi, the method accepts a series, so should work fine too. In your code, you were passing the string "date" which is obviously not in a datetime format. If you pass the actual series object it should work.

Comment: It can take `int, float, str, datetime, list, tuple, 1-d array, Series, DataFrame/dict-like` look at the [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)

Answer (score 0):

You actually need to pass the *correct format*, the format you have passed to the `datetime` function doesn't match the records that your array has, and and the correct format for the data you have is `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f`:

```py
pd.to_datetime(data, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')

#Output
DatetimeIndex(['2015-08-26 10:24:48.127000',        '2015-08-26 10:26:41',
                      '2015-08-26 10:27:52',        '2015-08-26 10:18:11',
                      '2015-08-26 10:21:39',        '2015-08-26 10:23:05'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Answer (score 0):

When passing the `date` to `pd.to_dateframe` you did not select the column.

The below code gives a `df['date']` column which consists of datetime objects.

```
import pandas as pd

date_dict= {'date': ['2015-08-26 10:24:48.127', '2015-08-26 10:26:41.000',
       '2015-08-26 10:27:52.000', '2015-08-26 10:18:11.000',
       '2015-08-26 10:21:39.000', '2015-08-26 10:23:05.000']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=date_dict)

df['date']= pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")

print(df['date'])
```

prints

```
0   2015-08-26 10:24:48.127
1   2015-08-26 10:26:41.000
2   2015-08-26 10:27:52.000
3   2015-08-26 10:18:11.000
4   2015-08-26 10:21:39.000
5   2015-08-26 10:23:05.000
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```